# How can I get data from axios promise object?

Tags: javascript, axios

I want to get variable from axios Promise data but it doesn't assign my variable.

```
const axios = require('axios');

let url = 'localhost:3000'
let id = ''
let token = 'my-token'

let api = axios.create({
    baseURL: url,
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
})

const getNotices = function (id, token) {
    var arr = []
    let result = api
        .request({
            url: `/notices/${id}/${token}`,
            method: "get",
        })
        .then(res => {
            arr = res.data
            console.log('in', arr)
        })
    console.log('out', arr)
    return arr
}

getNotices(id, token)
```

I want to print 'arr' but the result is different 'inside' and 'outside' of the api.

the result of code below is

```
out []
in [Array(3)]
```

I don't know why it's different.

I want to use this code for vuejs module but I can't export the data.

---

edit - tyskr's code like this

```
const getNotices = function (id, token) {
    return api
        .request({
            url: `/notices/${id}/${token}`,
            method: "get",
        })
        .then(res => {
            return res.data
        })
}

getNotices(id, token).then(function (arr) {
    console.log(arr)
})
```

but I can't access yet like this

```
const getNotices = function (id, token) {
    return api
        .request({
            url: `/notices/${id}/${token}`,
            method: "get",
        })
        .then(res => {
            return res.data
        })
}
var result = []
getNotices(id, token).then(function (arr) {
    result = arr
})
```

I think they have different scopes right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use async await like below.

```
const getNotices = async function (id, token) {
var arr = []
let result = await api
    .request({
        url: `/notices/${id}/${token}`,
        method: "get",
    })
    .then(res => {
        arr = res.data
        console.log('in', arr)
    })
    console.log('out', arr) // this line is executing before the response you get from url so we need to use async await
    return arr
```

Answer (score 1):

if you re-arranged the code in the following manner:

```
const getNotices = function (id, token) {
    var arr = []
    return api
        .request({
            url: `/notices/${id}/${token}`,
            method: "get",
        })
        .then(res => {
            arr = res.data
        })
}

getNotices(id, token).then(function(arr){
    console.log(arr); //should solve your issue
})
```

Then you should be able to get a consistent `arr` value.

Let me know if that does not work ...

Comment: Oh I think your intention is - 'return res.data' in api and return api at getNotices. -
and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the first index of the response

```js
const axios = require('axios');

let url = 'localhost:3000'
let id = ''
let token = 'my-token'

let api = axios.create({
  baseURL: url,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
})

const getNotices = function(id, token) {
  var arr = []
  let result = api
    .request({
      url: `/notices/${id}/${token}`,
      method: "get",
    })
    .then(res => {
      arr = res.data[0]
      console.log('in', arr)
    })
  console.log('out', arr)
  return arr
}

getNotices(id, token)
```